# How to sort table in columns using Django?

Tags: django, sorting

I have some tables in html like this:
...

```
<th>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <p class="fw-normal size-12 text-label mb-0 d-inline-block"></p>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-down ms-2 text-gray-dark size-12"></i>
    </div>
 </th>
```

...
I want to sort them using an arrow, but I have to use Django here. I didn't find much materials online. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you have create every column header as a link, example :

```
<th><a href="?order_by=address">Address</a></th>
```